# How can i perform constructor overloading in python?

Tags: python, constructor, overloading

I have an employee class which I would like to fill in two different ways, and would like to know do this by constructor overloading

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay

    def __init__(self, data):
        (self.first, self.last, self.pay) = data
```

This is because, either I have to initialise the class like

```
Employee('John','Smith',3000)
```

Or I would like to initialise the class by passing a tuple like

```
data = ('John','Smith',3000)
Employee(data)
```

Comment: There is no constructor/method/function overloading in Python. You can use either optional keyword-parameters, or decide what to do based on the type of the parameter. For this specific case, however, you can just do `Employee(*data)`, unpacking the tuple to the individual parameters.

Comment: If instead of `Employee(data)` you used `Employee(*data)`, you could use the single, straight-forward constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't, really. You *could* mess around with a definition like

```
def __init__(self, *args):
```

then do lots of processing that checks the number of arguments, the type of the first argument, etc. Or, you can simply be explicit and define a *separate* constructor whose name describes exactly what it does. The class method can do some validation on the tuple before passing its contents to the default constructor.

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay

    @classmethod
    def from_tuple(cls, t):
        if len(t) != 3:
            raise ValueError("Wrong number of items in the tuple")

        return cls(*t)

data = ('John','Smith',3000)
Employee.from_tuple(data)
```

Of course, the simplicity of the class method's definition suggests that you don't need to go to this much trouble: if you know the tuple has the right number and kinds of values, just unpack `data` for use with the default constructor.

```
Employee(*data)
```

---

By "default constructor", I mean the method which `Employee.__new__` resolves to. `Employee.__init__` is technically an *initializer*, invoked when appropriate on an already constructed instance returned by `__new__`.